# How to put a nickname in a C++ chat application?

Tags: c++, chat

So I made this C++ chat app and it doesn't work. 
So basically I just want to enter a nickname and then connect to the masterserver. Help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


SOCKADDR_IN addr;

SOCKET sConnect;

// For this we need to send two information at one time:
// 1. The main message
// 2. The ID

// To send more than one information I will use a struct
struct Buffer
{
    string ID;
    char Message[256];
};

int ClientThread()
{
    Buffer sbuffer;

    char buffer[sizeof(sbuffer)] = {0};

    for(;; Sleep(10))
    {
        // The server will send a struct to the client
        // containing message and ID
        // But send only accepts a char as buffer parameter
        // so here we need to recv a char buffer and then
        // we copy the content of this buffer to our struct
        if(recv(sConnect, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer), NULL))
        {
            memcpy(&sbuffer, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer));
            cout << "<Client " << sbuffer.ID << ":> " << sbuffer.Message     <<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}    

int main()
{
system("cls");

int RetVal = 0;

WSAData wsaData;
WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
RetVal = WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData);
if(RetVal != 0)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Winsock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    exit(1);
}

sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
addr.sin_port        = htons(1234);
addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;

cout << "Connect to Masterserver? [ENTER]" <<endl;
getchar();
RetVal = connect(sConnect, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

if(RetVal != 0)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Could not connect to server", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    main();
}
else
{
    string ID;
            cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
            cin >> ID;

    cout << "Connected" <<endl;

    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) ClientThread, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    for(;; Sleep(10))
    {
        char* buffer = new char[256];
        ZeroMemory(buffer, 256);

        cin >> buffer;
        getchar();

        send(sConnect, buffer, 256, NULL);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do the clients give their nickname?

Comment: Your code won't compile since there is no code.

Comment: It seems you don't really understand the basics of C++. Also we have no idea what the code of "a chat application made in C++" looks like and we're not psychic, so a short snippet of relevant code may help.

Comment: Start with a simpler project. If you don't know how to ask for a nick name, you're not ready to build a chat app.

Answer (score 1):

As for your problem, you don't actually send the id to the server, so the server will never know about it.

You do have a couple of other problems: In the clients input-send loop you mix new C++ stream input with old C `FILE` input. That will cause problems as those two systems are completely different and separate. Also, I recommend you use `std::string` for the input instead, and probably [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) as well.

Another problem in that loop is that you *always* send 256 bytes, no matter how much input you get from the user.

And a third, and very serious problem, is that you leak 256 bytes in each loop. C++ is not garbage-collected, what you allocate you have to free. That's yet another reason to use `std::string`.

And finally, you don't check for errors when reading or sending, meaning if the user presses the EOF key-sequence (<kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> on Linux/OSX) you will never know about it. You also don't check for errors neither from sending or receiving, and you don't check for a closed connection as well.